# How can I make the height of a div bigger onclick of a button and then change back to it's original height when click again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div `id="coding"` set on `height:300px` on `CSS`.
when I click another div `id="menu"`, I want #coding to change it's height to `800px`. I managed to do that like this

```
<script>
    function changec() {
        document.getElementById('coding').style.height = "800px";
    }
</script>
```

Now, when click the #menu again, I want the height to get back to it's original `300px` value. Can someone help? The code is:

HTML

```
<div id="coding">
<div id="menu" onclick="changec()">≡</div>
...
</div>
```

CSS

```
#coding{
    ...
    height:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple check if the value is set - remove it (then CSS height will take over).

```
function changec() {
       var xDiv = document.getElementById('coding');

       if (xDiv.style.height == '') 
           xDiv.style.height = '800px'
       else 
           xDiv.style.height = ''
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ygalanter/BLE6N/

Answer (score 1):

one of the solution for your problem is as follows:
First count how many times you click on #menu
now depending on your expectation you can change the javascript as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    function changec() {
        count++;
        if(count%2==1)
            document.getElementById("coding").style.height = "800px";
        else
            document.getElementById("coding").style.height = "300px";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I've never seen this approach before, and it's honestly good. But doing it this way, you are treating as certain that:

1) The initial height is **always** going to be 300px.
2) Though easily amendable, you are fixing the amounts of behaviours to be 2 : toggling between 800 and 300px ... quite a hassle, no?

Comment: Ok I understand... For these issue I already give an another solution below. I this one helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changec() {
        var currentheight = document.getElementById('coding').clientHeight;
        if (currentheight == 300)
            document.getElementById('coding').style.height = "800px";
        else if (currentheight == 800)
            document.getElementById('coding').style.height = "300px";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you tagged jQuery since you didn't use it, but still...Considering the possibility that you are willing to use/learn it, I created a jsFiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/Tm2Hd/.

**CSS**:

```
#coding{
    border:1px solid black; /*optional: Keep track of your div's expand*/
    height:300px;
    }
#coding.larger{
    height:800px;
    }
```

**JS**:

```
 function changeHeight() {
    if($('#coding.larger').length>0)
    {
       $('#coding').removeClass("larger");
    }
    else
    {
       $('#coding').addClass("larger");
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="coding">
    <!--<div onclick="changeHeight()">≡</div> 
       Personally, I don't suggest using divs as clickable objects... Why don't you use buttons instead?
  -->
   <button onclick="changeHeight()">≡</button> 
    ...
</div>
```

My solution to your problem is: Create a new class named **larger**, pointing to your div, and toggle between this and the original whenever you click the button.